How to implement the csp react Apex charts?
I want implement the content security police in the react Apex Charts but dont want to use unsafe-inline this the content which i am using
const content = "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: ; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com  https://fonts.gstatic.com cdn.jsdelivr.net 'nonce-random'; font-src 'self' data: https://fonts.gstatic.com ;  connect-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com https://api.openai.com; manifest-src 'self'; base-uri 'self' ; form-action 'self'; frame-src 'self';";

i try giving the cdn.jsdelivr.net  in the content



Looks liek it was fixed in https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/releases/tag/v3.41.1 ?

i am using  "apexcharts": "^3.49.1", still got ui distortion in inline style
